# Multi line comment in oracle sqlplus

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have ran the below statements in sqlplus. It inserts duplicate of row 2. In log I have found that i row created after the comment line as well.
So, here I am asking the multi line comment should have a space between /* and comment and */ ?

```
insert into table values (1);  
insert into table values (2);  
/*comments here*/  
insert into table values (3);  
commit;
```

Log:

```
SQL> insert into table values (1); 

1 row created.  

SQL> insert into table values (2);  

1 row created.  

**SQL> /*comments here*/  

1 row created.**  

SQL> insert into table values (3);  

1 row created.  

select A from table;  
A  
------------  
1  
2  
2  
3
```

Comment: if i understand correctly, if you dont want your code to work, you must wrap it in comment. `like /* insert into table values (3);   */`

Comment: The / at the beginning of the comment makes the last statement run again and so the extra insert.

Answer (score 5):

All,

I have tried in sqlplus.  We need to give the space or new line between /* and following characters. So it treated as multi line comment.

correct syntax:

**`/* comments here */`**

or

**`/*
comments here
*/`**

Wrong syntax:

**`/*comments here*/`**

Comment: Ha! So true. So it wasn't an extra slash, but "no space" - though, it is required only at the beginning of the comment: `/* comments here*/`, the trailing space isn't required.

Answer (score 1):

I presume that your code contains an extra forward slash. Have a look:

```
SQL> create table test (id number);

Table created.

SQL> insert into test values (1);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into test values (2);

1 row created.

SQL> /* comments
SQL> here
SQL> */
SQL> /                   --> this one; it executes the last command in buffer ...

1 row created.           --> ... and results with yet another "2" begin inserted

SQL> insert into test values (3);

1 row created.

SQL> select * from test;

        ID
----------
         1
         2
         2
         3

SQL>
```

Without it, everything is OK:

```
SQL> truncate table test;

Table truncated.

SQL> insert into test values (1);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into test values (2);

1 row created.

SQL> /* comments
SQL> here
SQL> */
SQL> insert into test values (3);

1 row created.

SQL> select * from test;

        ID
----------
         1
         2
         3

SQL>
```